# How can i get value from ManyToMany table?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two classes: Child and Guardian

in Guardian class i have that field:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "guardian_child", schema = "schema",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "guardianid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "childid"))
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have table guardian_child in my Postgres. And now i need to get all children by id of guardian? Need i create special entity and repository for this table? Or how can i do it?

Comment: If you just need ids, why not use a plain query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Many-to-Many query jpql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592533/many-to-many-query-jpql)

Comment: how can i use plain query in controller's method body?

Comment: how can i call this inside method?

Comment: You can @Autowire the EntityManager, and explicitly run the query you want, i.e. `entityManager.createQuery(<your JPQL query>)`. Also, take a look at this article about how to model Many-To-Many relationships in JPA: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You can get data using JPQL query like this: @Query(SELECT g FROM Guardian JOIN g.children c)... if it doesn't work let me know once again